# c++ project managed with git runs differently with same input on different machines

Tags: c++, git, github

I have a c++ project that runs significantly differently on two different machines when given identical input. I expect the program to run essentially identically on both machines. When I run

```
git push origin master
```

on my local machine, where I've been writing the program, it tells me that the repository (on github) is up-to-date. I've done

```
git clone
```

on the second machine, which is a compute cluster, and compiled the code there with no errors. The code runs on the cluster just fine, but seems to run similarly to an older version of the program, rather than the version that I have on my personal computer. My question is then this: is it possible that the github version is somehow out-of-date, or that the syncing up of my local version of the code with the github version got messed up along the way?

Bear in mind that I'm a newbie when it comes to git. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've found that this is probably due to some sort of difference in the architecture of the two machines. They're both x86_64 Intel processors, but a fast approximation to the exponential function, which depends on the size of doubles and endianness, doesn't work on the second machine. Long story short: this isn't a problem with git.

Comment: Magical bugs? Sounds like undefined behaviour

Comment: Did you actually commit your local changes to your local repository before pushing?

Comment: Yes, I committed them. git status reports no changes.

Comment: To rule git out as being the source of the issue (from what you said, it shouldn't be), you should add some way to have the program spit out a version number to a log, to allow you to be sure it's actually the version you expect. If it is indeed being updated, then it would appear to have nothing to do with Git.

Comment: I've tried make clean && make on the remote machine, but the program still runs differently there. I don't know how I could meaningfully add a version number to the project, though. Definitely, some of the files are being updated. I'm downloading the source and input files from github and run diff on them and my local versions. Any other ideas? This is really baffling me.

Comment: I've found the answer to my own question, and it has nothing to do with git. The problem was that an approximation to the exponential function doesn't work on the architecture the cluster uses, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clone the repos after your last push? The normal procedure is usually to use clone to get any backstory up to this point in time and then use "git pull origin master" to update after that (or, as the documentation states, preferably "git fetch origin" followed by "git merge origin/master master", which is equivalent, but allows you to be more specific regarding how the merge should happen, if it's a simple case of developing somewhere and deploying elsewhere then use pull).

As is stated in the comments above, the procedure for pushing stuff is the following:

Step 1: Add files:

    `git add -i` 
to add any files you have changed and want to commit, alternatively you can use:
    `git add <filename>` to be specific for every file, instead of using the interactive tool.
Step 2: Commit those files
`git commit -m <Commit message>`
or ommit the -m to have your favourite editor pop up to allow you to define the commit message there.
Step 3: Push these changes to your repos (if needed)
Remember that if there are more people or computers pushing to the repos, you should be up to date locally before doing this, by doing a:

`git pull origin master`
Resolve any conflicts that might ensue, and push:
`git push origin master`

 Note that master specifies the branch to push and pull from, replace it with any other branch you might be using currently (if not master, which is the default).

Answer (score 0):

I would clone the git repository on the first machine in a different location and see if it executes differently first.

If it does, I would then diff the clone's .git folder on the first machine with the clone on the compute cluster.

The rationale is this:

- All information about the repository is contained in the .git folder.
- Given a .git folder, you can re-create the entire working tree.
- Therefore, if your .git folder is the same, the working tree that is created must also be the same (assuming that the file systems you check out on to both have the same permissions and case sesntivity settings)

If the diff says the folders are identical, then it's not git's fault and I would look at the build environment and the code.

Hope this helps.